# How to look for better hardware for my computer?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building

I have Iball Designer PC (model No not confirmed) and that have motherboard http://www.flipkart.com/gigabyte-ga-g41mt-s2-motherboard/p/itmd5rrrzwpndajr?pid=MBDD5RRRBVQBXEZM&ref=17c8f5e4-60b2-46c3-a689-bed5d0b4cf3b&srno=t_1&otracker=from-search&query=gigabyte%20ga-g41mt-s2%20motherboard

I have 4GB ram on it and Intel core 2 duo as processor. I want to replace the motherboard so Someone help me how I can look for hardware.

1. How to replace motherboard that will be compatible with my existing hardware.

[image]

Comment: Is the current motherboard broken?

Comment: No, it's working fine @JoelCoehoorn I just thing I can upgrade it so I can put more RAM on it. Do you have any idea.

Comment: based on the image you have two slots for RAM, and one of them is free. If you currently have 4GB installed, that means your current board can accept 4GB DDR3 sticks, and you can double your RAM without purchasing a new board. When shopping for RAM, try to get a stick that will match the exact timings of your current RAM, so that you can use dual-channel mode.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes, I will got my 4gb ram in next days. what I am looking for is a motherboard so I can installed some more ram and a better processor like I3,i5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a board that uses the LGA 775 socket type and accepts DDR3 RAM. Any board that meets those requirements will likely work with the parts you described. Also look for a Micro-ATX form factor to make sure it fits in your current case. Prices should start as low as around $40US.

...but... why?

If you want a faster computer, the motherboard can be a good place to start, but only as a platform that will allow you to use a newer cpu and RAM. It's unlikely to make your computer any faster on it's own, and if you get one that allows you to use your current cpu and RAM, you won't really gain anything. If you're looking for some other capability, or if the current motherboard is broken, those seem like important things to mention in the question.

**Update:**

Based on your comments and the image, you should be able to double your RAM without needing to purchase a new board. Just look for a single 4GB DDR3 chip (make sure you don't buy two 2GB chips). Best if the new RAM matches the timings of the old RAM... that will not only double the amount, but allow the RAM to also run *faster*. A quick search on NewEgg shows prices starting about $17US.

When it arrives, the new RAM will plug into the long skinny empty blue slot shown near the center of your image, directly above the CE mark.

Comment: Is LGA775 means different Processor not worked or will not fit on cabinet. What about Upgrade of processor to i3,i5. As you seen my current motherboard is not supported I3 or I5. Can you suggest me how I can start looking for hardware If I want to get more ram or processor like I3,i5.

Comment: If you want to upgrade to an i3 or i5, you need a motherboard with an LGA1155 socket. A LGA1155 board will not work with your current Core2 Duo cpu.

Comment: The author should confirm what LGA 775 CPUs are compatable with this motherboard. I have an LGA 775 motherboard, I just have one, that doesn't support anything past a Pent D.  He might be able to get a faster LGA 775 socket CPU without changing anything else.  Of course he will pay a premium to do this because they are EOL more then likely.

Comment: Also: these days, most computers have cpu time to spare. The cpu is rarely the bottleneck any more. But the RAM upgrade, and save the cpu and motherboard budget for an SSD (and graphics card if you're a gamer). You'll have better results this way.